# Java - Selenium Web Driver: Pulling date format MM/DD/YY from Excel and populating in the web field cause switch month and day to each other place

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I am trying to Pull date format MM/DD/YYYY from Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet and populate in the web field cause switch month and day to each other place and that cause script failure.

I want to populate date in the MM/DD/YYYY format(American Format) in the web field. However, in the web field date populate as DD/MM/YYYY.

Following date format I have in my excel sheet:

```
10/18/1976
```

When date populate in the web field then it populate as below:

```
18/10/1976
```

Following are my code:

```
package com.Test

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC20042 extends BaseClass{

 @Test
        public void registration() throws Exception, InterruptedException {
              FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\File\\Book2.xls");
              Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
              Sheet s=w.getSheet(2);


            try
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.getRows(); i++)
            {
            //Read data from excel sheet

                String s7 = s.getCell(6,i).getContents();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='__o3id9']")).sendKeys(s7);
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println(e);

            }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I was using Default date format in the excel sheet when I entered test data in the excel sheet as below:

[image: Default Date Format]

But then I realized that may be there is another customize date format in the cell format option which I updated as below and it worked for me now:

[image: Customize Date Format]